# gravity and layout:gravity properties not showing up in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gravity

I have a *LinearLayout* inside of which I have a *textView*. When I click on *textView* in **component tree** I don't see it's *gravity* property in **Properties** menu on the right side. I also don't see *layout:gravity* property.

[image: Properties]

Even after manually adding those properties in xml, I still don't see them.

Comment: what exactly is your issue? not showing or not working in your xml?

Comment: [This also worked for me, all the attributes reapear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173764/9890675)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click on the "two arrows" at the top of the **Properties** menu to see all the properties

[image]

If you want to see them in the base list, you can add them as "favorite attributes" by clicking on the star that appears when you hover your mouse over the left side of a property name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on View All Property (above two blue arrow icon) to open all property attributes.