# Missing attributes in layout editor in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I've got a problem with Android Studio version 3.2.1. I do not see in layout editor  most of attributes like for example id. I have got this bug probably after Android Studio's update. [image]

Comment: have you tried applying different theme? The option is above the layout 'AppTheme', click on it and choose a different theme.

Comment: That doesn't work

Comment: What's that view all attributes button in bottom right corner

Comment: Shows other attributes but not all of them. It stills doesn't show attribute like id, width, height and much more. This is not how this window should look like

Comment: @Brodeon Mac or PC?

Comment: This happened to me and none of these answers worked for me , i just update android studio and the problem fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete all android studio files (not just uninstall and except your projects). I didn't try Raynold's solution, so if you have any problem you can try it before deleting all the files.

Comment: Deleting and redownloading Android sdk is enough

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me.

- Exit android studio then make the below changes.
- Go to C:\Users\UserName.android and rename the build-cache folder to build-cache.bak
- Go to C:\Users\UserName.AndroidStudio3.2\system and rename these folders

  caches to caches.bak

  compiler to compiler.bak

  compile-server to compile-server.bak

  conversion to conversion.bak

  external_build_system to external_build_system.bak

  frameworks to frameworks.bak

  gradle to gradle.bak

  resource_folder_cache to resource_folder_cache.bak
- Open the Android Studio and open your project again.

[No IDEA annotations attached to the JDK 1.8 (C:\...), some issues will not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740240/no-idea-annotations-attached-to-the-jdk-1-8-c-some-issues-will-not-be-fo)

Comment: Saved my life with this answer - all the attributes are baack!

Comment: Thank Raynold ! Can i know how you knew the issue and how you solved it?

Comment: Doesn't work on Android Studio Chipmunk.  Why do simple stuff all of a sudden stop working on Android Studio and waste so much time?!  Google Engineers get paid so much to do what?!  QA is more important than shipping new features on half-baked products...

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me today. It was very frustrating, my entire gradle got messed up for unknown reason.
in build.gradle (Module: app), I had issues with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' .
```

I chose to suppress the warning at first, and they put

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

for me... Anyways, I replaced above line with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

and changed my `compileSdkVersion` to 26
and the attributes in layout editor came back alive.
so I guess that appcompat thing has to do with the layout editor.

Answer (score 0):

Down of the activity_main.xml window there is "Design" tab and "Text" tab. Click on design tab, select an item and voila: attributes window is on the right

Answer (score 0):

I updated the Android studio and restart my project and it solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Starting with Android Studio 3.0.1, all the fields from the Properties panel can now be found under the Attributes by selecting:

> View all attributes

Comment: It doesn't show all the atributes that I had in the past. Many attributes which I had in Attributes tab has gone

Comment: If that is the case try this: File > Invalidate Caches\Restart.

Comment: I tried this, also I tried: clean project, rebuild project, reinstalation of android studio. This problem doesn't appear in this one project, it is in all of android studio projects