# Can`t see all xml atributes in layout editor

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I don't know if I'm missing some point but I can't figure out how to show all the attributes in my xml layout editor. It only shows a few of them and even if I try to search for them they're not popping up. An example for a missing attribute in the image below would be "gravity" or "textsize".

Already tried to rebuild my project with cleaning cache.

[That's how it looks like at the moment for a TextView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB4il.png)

Thanks for any help

Comment: An answer should be : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927675/gravity-and-layoutgravity-properties-not-showing-up-in-android-studio-2-3

Comment: @LuxAeterna this could be the fix but I don't find the two arrows in newest Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a very long time to update my Android Studio.
Now I have the same window as you :

[image]

You can see I lost the two arrows button but I have the "All attributes" section, like you, and I have gravity :

[image]

My buildToolsVersion is '28.0.3'and  compileSdkVersion is 26.
Have you checked all your layouts?

Here is another solution :
[Missing attributes in the layout design - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843163/missing-attributes-in-the-layout-design-android-studio)

Comment: Thank you for all the effort! The link you've provided does really help :)